# LinkButton in Repeater Command does not fire on click

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a linkbutton in a Repeater that needs to fire a method in the codebehind when clicked, but the method never executes when the LinkButton is clicked.  Here is the HTML for the Repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptFeatures" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' 
            CommandName="listItem_Click" 
            CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "AccessListItemId") %>'>
        </asp:LinkButton><br />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Here is the method that needs to fire onClick:

```
protected void listItem_Click(object sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

The method never gets called as I have a breakpoint on the NotEmplementedException just to see if it hits.  Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Try This :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptFeatures" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptFeatures_OnItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' 
                CommandName="listClick"
                CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "AccessListItemId") %>'>
        </asp:LinkButton><br />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

protected void rptFeatures_OnItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName.Equals("listItem_Click"))
    {
        // your code
    }    
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work either.  Is there something else I need to do in the Repeater?

Comment: I am pretty much sure it should work. Did you try to put break point under this method and Page Load event. What happened ?

Comment: Second this try to comment 'CommandArgument' and see what happened

Answer (score 1):

Instead of CommandName Use onClick Event.

OnClick="listItem_Click"

Comment: This actually hits the method, but the parameter doesn't pass through.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add "OnItemCommand=listItem_ItemCommand" to the Repeater to Baseer Haider's answer.  The repeater now looks like this:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rptFeatures" runat="server" OnItemCommand="listItem_ItemCommand">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' CommandName="listClick"  CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "AccessListItemId") %>'></asp:LinkButton><br />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
```

Now it hits the method with arguments included:

```
        protected void listItem_ItemCommand (Object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName.Equals("listItem_Click"))
        {
            // your code
        }

    }
```

Comment: I "completed" the BASEER HAIDER response.
Delete this and mark the BASEER HAIDER response as the correct answer. He helped you see the problem.